# How to use Split for string in Beanshell?

Tags: split, jmeter, beanshell

I'm writing a Beanshell sampler in JMeter to read a file, in which I want to split each line by comma(,) and want to extract the values. I'm getting the first splitted string with index 0 but for next values with index 1, 2 and so... it is not giving the values.

`value = value.append(line.split(",")[2]);`

Here, for index 0 it is working all fine BUT for index more than 0, it fails.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you sure that your `line.split(",")` expression produces String array with length > 1? How do you know?

For instance the next code:

```
String line = "quick, brown, fox, jumped, over";
String[] words = line.split(",");
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  log.info(words[i]);
  if (i == 2) {
      log.info("Third word is: " + words[2]);
  }
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
2014/10/08 13:17:37 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: quick 
2014/10/08 13:17:37 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement:  brown 
2014/10/08 13:17:37 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement:  fox 
2014/10/08 13:17:37 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Third word is:  fox 
2014/10/08 13:17:37 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement:  jumped 
2014/10/08 13:17:37 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement:  over
```

I would recommend using logging all the values via `log.info` method and examining the output. Since JMeter 2.6 [Log Viewer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) is available and you should be able to see what's happening right in JMeter GUI as:

[image: Beanshell Logging]

For more Beanshell tips and tricks refer to [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide.

Comment: Actually, I made it work with for each loop at work. But, after watching your answer, I tried one more time and BOOM, now it's working...must have done some petty error. By the way, **THUMPS UP** for the _Log Viewer_ link, didn't knew that and it's AWESOME :) (Made my life with JMeter a more simpler :P )

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was familiar with split but always did print("..."); not log.info!  Log is much more convenient to use while debugging.